# GMM panel data model in R - no individual effects

Tags: r, panel-data, generalized-moments

I need to estimate the coefficients of a particular dynamic panel data model.

\begin{equation}
\ln(y_{i,t})=\alpha_0+\beta ln(y_{i,t-1})+\theta_t+ \varepsilon_{i,t}
\end{equation}

Currently, I'm trying to do so using *plm* package - especially *pgmm* function. The problem is that the *effects* parameter accepts only two values. It's either "individual" or "twoways". In both cases it's not valid for my model as I do not consider any individual effects (hence the intercept term 0).

Do you know how to solve this problem? I'm not particularly bounded to the *plm* package of course.

Comment: Are the \theta_t parameters fixed or random?

Comment: I assume it is fixed

Comment: Could you just estimate it with OLS?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong l but as far as I know the existence of the "y" term in the RHS of the equation violates the assumption of the OLS (regarding the lack of correlation of the error term and the RHS variables) which in result leads to the inefficiency of the estimator (and in case of OLS to the biasness?) That's why I decided to use SYS-GMM estimator in the first place